# What is this color theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, color-scheme

Does anyone know what the color theme [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/), [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) (option "MDN like" in settings) or [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) use in their code examples? I would like to use it for my VS Code editor.

Examples - [MDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEaPO.png), [Codepen (MDN like theme)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wXnW.png), [Prettier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alpQ2.png)

Comment: choose you favorite light theme and just change the colors for the syntax highlighting based on the colors found on the sites

Comment: Exactly! I will do so. Thanks. In addition, I have already found all the colors of this theme on this site [Prism](https://prismjs.com/). Maybe they are the authors of this theme.

Comment: Are you going to support all the variants of PrismJS? Also look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.prism